# Kubuntu 13.04 SMB Protocol source

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu, kde, samba, dolphin

I have a share on an Ubuntu machine that has some movies on it. After installing KDE 13.04 I cannot play the movies on the share from Dolphin.

I get the following error:

```
The following plugin is required:
*SMB protocol source
Do you want to search for this now?
Yes / No
```

No option helps.

I know I can mount the share properly and access it from there, any other solution to make it work properly from Dolphin?

Comment: Possibly related bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253547 I assume it's an issue with the media player used, or as some have written with a protocol missing in the corresponding *.desktop file. Can you check if VLC works?

Comment: VLC works, I am quite sure that I have tried it before but now after a reinstall it works just fine. Dragon Player still not working.

Comment: Then it's either missing a plugin to read from SMB sources completely or the SMB protocol needs to be added in the *.desktop file, as shown in the bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253547), I read:

> OK then it's clear: what's missing is
>
> ```
>  X-KDE-Protocols=http,ftp,smb
> ```
>
> in vlc's .desktop file.

You may wish to try that.

Comment: I have tried that before it did not work. Right now VLC works (without this change) Dragon player does not.